# Colocar dados de um csv em variaveis php

Tags: php

Olá, tenho um codigo php que pega os dados do arquivo csv inserido pelo usuario, ele mostra tudo em uma mesma variavel, preciso separar cada coluna em variaveis diferentes.

O codigo esta colocando todo conteudo do cvs em apenas uma variavel "$categoria", preciso divir o que tem na coluna categoria do csv (primeira categoria) na variavel categoria o que tem na segunda coluna (valor) na segunda variavel $valor

```
if (isset($_POST['importSubmit'])) {

        $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');

        if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $csvMimes)) {

            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {

                $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');


                fgetcsv($csvFile);

                while (($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE) {

                    $categoria   = $line[0];
                    echo "Cat: " . $categoria ?? null;
                    $valor_cat  = $line[1];
                    echo "Valor: " . $valor_cat ?? null;
                }
            }


            fclose($csvFile);
        }
    }
```

[image: Imagem de como esta exibindo]

Comment: A pergunta não está clara. O código já faz o que esta pedindo. A ele não faz, especifique qual o problema é qual é o resultado esperado.

Answer (score -2):

Na função fgetcsv você pode passar o parametro de quebra do seu CSV, pelo visto é o ponto e virgula (;).

Sugiro que veja na documentação: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgetcsv.php